# Changing a .click function button to load right away instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html2canvas

I'm loading html2canvas which has the following script:

```
 $(function() {
             $("#btnSave").click(function() {
                                 html2canvas($(".widget"), {
                                             onrendered: function(canvas) {
                                             theCanvas = canvas;
                                             document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                                             // Convert and download as image
                                             Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
                                             $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                                             // Clean up
                                             //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
                                             }
                                             });
                                 });
             });
```

I have a button with the id "btnSave" that when clicked it generates my canvas image. Now, instead of having to click the button I would prefer it to load on the page automatically. Is this possible?

jsFiddle to what I'm working with: https://jsfiddle.net/h5ase09f/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it after the document loads using the ready callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     html2canvas($(".widget"), {
       onrendered: function(canvas) {
         theCanvas = canvas;
         document.body.appendChild(canvas);

         // Convert and download as image
         Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
         $("#img-out").append(canvas);
         // Clean up
         //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
       }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $(document).ready instead of $(id).click and it will load automatically.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var widget = $(".widget")[0]
  var result = html2canvas(widget).then(function(canvas) {
    console.log('rendered');
    theCanvas = canvas;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    // Convert and download as image
    Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
    $("#img-out").append(img);
  }).catch(
    // Log the rejection reason
    (reason) => {
      console.log('Handle rejected promise (' + reason + ') here.');
    });

  console.log('running');
  console.log(result);

});
```

```css
/* ------- BLACK BOX ------- */

.template2,
.template3,
.template4 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  max-height: 50%;
}


/* ------- ADDRESS POSITIONING ------- */

.template2 .data {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 111;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Lato;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-top: 14%;
}

.template3 .data {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 111;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Lato;
  padding-left: 12%!important;
  padding-top: 14%!important;
}

.template4 .data {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 111;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Lato;
  padding-left: 9%!important;
  padding-top: 14%!important;
}


/* ------- TITLE TEXT ------- */

.template2 .data h2 {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 5.6rem;
  line-height: 1;
}

.template3 .data h2 {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 5.6rem;
  line-height: 1;
}

.template4 .data h2 {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 5.6rem;
  line-height: 1;
}


/* ------- ADDRESS TEXT ------- */

.template2 .data p {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: arial;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-weight: regular;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.template3 .data p {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: lato;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.template4 .data p {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: lato;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.line {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 45px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/canvas2image/0.1/canvas2image.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cotala.com/social/profile/css/script.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cotala.com/social/profile/js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="off-canvas-wrapper">
  <div class="off-canvas-wrapper-inner" data-off-canvas-wrapper>

    <center><input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save" />
      <div id="img-out"></div>
    </center>

    <div class="column">
      <div id="html2canvas">
        <div class="widget thumbnail">

          <div class="template2">
            <div class="absolute">
              <div class="data">
                <h2>JUST<br>SOLD</h2>
                <hr class="line">
                <p>1234&nbsp;Address&nbsp;Avenue<br>Langley<br>Walnut&nbsp;Grove</p>

              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="http://cotala.com/social/profile/images/templates/blank.png">
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
```

Note Snippet may not work here. Was getting cross domain security errors. Working fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/q04quu74/

Comment: `$(function() ` is shortcut (and preferred approach) for `$(document).ready(function()`. No need to nest `$(document).ready(function()` inside

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#btnSave" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just run this on the onload function of the body.  [This](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onload) is a pretty good example.

---

Alternatively

Update your body to be  `<body onload="load">`

In your js you can use the following

```
function load() {
  html2canvas($(".widget"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      theCanvas = canvas;
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);

      // Convert and download as image
      Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
      $("#img-out").append(canvas);
      // Clean up
      //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
    }
  });
}
```